Does driving from a home office to a leased office (LLC) qualify as business miles? important context
I understand on the surface, the answer is no. However, digging a little deeper I see paragraphs like this

If you work out of your home and your home is your principal place of business, you can generally deduct the cost of traveling from home to any business destination.

https://www.wolterskluwer.com/en/expert-insights/business-use-of-a-car-can-be-deductible
So for an LLC with an office lease (official co. address), with a sole owner, who works from home a lot, more than from an office, is it ok?
Thanks!

what functions do you only do at each location? Is one where you meet with clients? Is one where a key piece of hardware can be operated?

@mhoran-psprep it consulting, IT in both locations. Occasionally, if they come to town, we will meet in the office, but it's more often that we go in their direction, which typically involves air travel.

If the office is there just to meet with clients, why do you have it? Surely you can't meet with clients often enough to require an office to yourself? Renting an office space when you need it would be much more cost effective.

I’m voting to close this question because from the OP's clarifications in the comments this is not a disregarded entity SMLLC as was initially implied, but rather a business with multiple employees which has a full office environment. This is off-topic for this forum, and I strongly advise reaching out to a tax/legal professional for a proper opinion on the matter.

@djclayworth - that would be more cost effective, agreed :)

Driving between two offices of the company can (canada) be a business driving expense. If one of those offices happens to be in your home, then it might appear that driving from home to the office is deductible, but that's not what is qualifying. Ditto driving from one of your offices to a client location or to the airport in order to fly to a client.
Anecdote: My business has an office attached to my home. It contains furniture and equipment that belongs to the business, and confidential paperwork. In 30+ years I can count on one hand the number of times clients have come to it, but staff have, and on one occasion a CRA auditor who was specifically interested in entertainment and transportation expenses including our use of the company-owned car. We at that time drove to our other (rented) office regularly. The audit found no irregularities.
If the company is not paying rent (to you, the person who owns the home) or other business-related expenses at the location, you just happen to enjoy working there more than at your company-leased location, then you're probably not driving between two offices of the company.

Thanks. Curious if you looked at that reference, specifically this paragraph
"If you work out of your home and your home is your principal place of business, you can generally deduct the cost of traveling from home to any business destination."
Can't upvote yet, sorry!

I mean, I saw it, but it's not an actionable sentence, what with "generally" and the disclaimer about principal place of business. My last paragraph is about that -- what makes something your principal place of business? Or for that matter even a place of business at all, principal or otherwise?


So for an LLC with an office lease (official co. address), with a sole owner, who works from home a lot, more than from an office, is it ok?

No. Commute to the office is not a business expense, whether you're the business owner or an employee. See 26 CFR 1.274-14:

(a) General rule. Except as provided in this section, no deduction is allowed for any expense incurred for providing any transportation, or any payment or reimbursement, to an employee of the taxpayer in connection with travel between the employee's residence and place of employment


That applies if OP is treating themselves as an employee of themselves. It's not clear that it applies to a self-employed person.

That link says "(3) Place of employment. The term place of employment means the employee's regular or principal (if more than one regular) place of business. An employee's place of employment does not include temporary or occasional places of employment. An employee must have at least one regular or principal place of business."
Seems they'd be ok if they can establish that their home is the principal place of business?

@GaneshSittampalam yeah, but an LLC with a single employee/member wouldn't need an office if it wasn't for that person to work there, right?

Clarification. The LLC has employees. They are allowed and do work remotely most of the time but also meet in the office on occasion.

@TMax seems like the situation is more complex than you initially presented. I suggest you discuss this with a licensed professional (EA/CPA/Attorney licensed in your State).

@littleadv - thanks. To be fair, doesn't that advice belong on most if not all tax related questions ever posted to this forum? :)
This is a nuanced question and I appreciate some be willing to look into it with that nuance in mind.
My accountant did state that commuting to and from work are not business miles.

@TMax this forum is not intended for nuanced legal advice, it's intended to explain the trivial and non-controversial issues. Once you need to dig into the very specifics of your personal facts and circumstances it becomes less financial literacy question and more a request for a professional opinion. For a professional opinion you need a professional.

@littleadv, I think I've gotten good advice so far to my nuanced question - intended or not. If you get enough support to close, then I will have to live with that. As I said, I did talk to my accountant about it first. Thanks.

What's the point? Our opinion is of no consequence. In case of audit you cannot say to the IRS "but some randos on an internet forum told me it's OK". This forum is for general education purposes only, your question is clearly seeking for a specific legal advice about your personal circumstances.


You can’t deduct the costs of taking a bus, trolley, subway, or taxi, or of driving a car between your home and your main or regular place of work. These costs are personal commuting expenses.

https://www.irs.gov/publications/p463#en_US_2023_publink100033916
This would seem to say that you can deduct the cost of traveling to a location that isn't your regular place of work.

Thanks. I think my question is a bit nuanced than that and revolves around the definition of the principal place of business. The facts are that an LLC owner does work from home most of the time, another office location is there and this is an official LLC address, there are employees who can work out of home or an office.

I think the question hinges on what "regular place of work" means. Is it where you individually usually work (e.g. at home for a remote worker) or the employer's office.
